# JNDI call does not fail when the certificate is deleted for LDAPS communication

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, jndi, openldap

We have a requirement to support LDAPS for all our directory login through JNDI

Have set the "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" to the trust store I need and have added certificates 
to a trusted java keystore.

The JNDI call is successful for the first time import of any certificates. But further updates to the keystore like updating or deleting it is not picked up by JNDI. We are trying to communicate with a microsoft AD server.

The code is running in a jetty webapp and restarting the webapp to pick up latest keystore data is out of question.

Is there any way in which the reload can be addressed?

Regards,

Binoy

Answer (score 2):

You can create a ReloadableX509TrustManager.

Something like shown on:
http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/managing-a-dynamic-java-trust-store/

Comment: Looked in the site found a pretty decent implementation as well. 
Pasting the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394864/jndi-ldaps-custom-hostnameverifier-and-trustmanager and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035910/ssl-connection-to-ldap-using-certitificates-and-custom-ssl-socket-factory

Hope this helps. Had to search a lot for this.

Comment: Looked in the site found a pretty decent implementation as well. 
Pasting the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394864/jndi-ldaps-custom-hostnameverifier-and-trustmanager and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035910/ssl-connection-to-ldap-using-certitificates-and-custom-ssl-socket-factory

Hope this helps. Had to search a lot for this.